How to refactor similar functions in Python?
I have defined multiple functions where I search for a specific pydantic model in a list of pydantic models based on some attribute value.
SocketIOUserSessionID = str
RoomWithIndex = tuple[Room, RoomIndex]
RSStateWithIndex = tuple[RSState, int]
RSPacketSavedRecordWithIndex = tuple[RSPacketSavedRecordsContainer, int]


def find_room_by_id(self, id: UUID | str, where: list[Room]) -> RoomWithIndex | None:
    room = next(filter(lambda room: room.id == id, where), None)
    if room is None:
        return None
    index = where.index(room)
    return room, index

def find_room_by_session(self, session: SocketIOUserSessionID, where: list[Room]) -> RoomWithIndex | None:
    room = next(filter(lambda room: session in room.sessions, where), None)
    if room is None:
        return None
    index = where.index(room)
    return room, index

def find_rs_state_by_room_id(self, room_id: str, where: list[RSState]) -> RSStateWithIndex | None:
    rs_state = next(filter(lambda rs_state: rs_state.room_id == room_id, where), None)
    if rs_state is None:
        return None
    index = where.index(rs_state)
    return rs_state, index

def find_saved_record_by_room_id(self, room_id: str, where: list[RSPacketSavedRecordsContainer]) -> RSPacketSavedRecordWithIndex | None:
    saved_record = next(filter(lambda saved_records: saved_records.room_id == room_id, where), None)
    if saved_record is None:
        return None
    index = where.index(saved_record)
    return saved_record, index

How to write a generic function (with typing) to refactor such code? I heard of functools.singledispatch decorator but I am not sure that this is the right case to use it.
    def find_value_by_attr(self):
        ?


I tried to generalize the four functions as much as possible - here's where I ended up:
def find_model(
    self,
    iid: UUID | str,
    where: list[Any],
    filter_attr: str,
) -> tuple[Any, int] | None:
    if (
        model := next(
            filter(lambda model: iid == getattr(model, filter_attr), where)
        )
    ):
        return model, where.index(model)

The find_model function takes

an iid (item ID) in place of id, session, or room_id (NOTE: naming this iid avoids shadowing the builtin id)
a where list just as before
a filter_attr which is the string name of the attribute you want to filter, e.g. 'id', 'sessions', or 'room_id'

The only thing this doesn't quite cover is the filtering case of find_room_by_session which is using in instead of == in the filter lambda. If anyone more clever than I would care to weigh in, I'm open to it!
If I may take a moment to editorialize: I like the idea of using @singledispatch for this, but it doesn't get you away from writing multiple function prototypes anyway...if the goal it 'less code', then @singledispatch doesn't help much in that regard.

That was the exact reason why I didn't code singledispatch -> I think it's more about different approaches of handling different argument types, rather than saving code. I completely forgot about getattr and stuck on it :) thank you, I'll mark as accepted

@SlavaPasedko Yeah, @singledispatch is more of a type-wrangling tool - still cool though! Glad I could help!

My personal preference would be to use directly the generators like this : model:= next((m for m in where if getattr(m, filter_attr)), None), whereby m==model, but as i said it's my personal preference.

@baskettaz I like that approach! Good suggestion.

I figured out how to make a generic function with help of "operator" module. Look in answers if you're interested. I think it lacks a fail-fast check if function passed is defined in operator module and nowhere else. But it's for your choice

To me it seems that the only way of doing it is to create another function that takes in a conditional function:
def find_value_by_attr(self, where, f):
    val = next(filter(f, where), None)
    if val is None:
        return None
    index = where.index(val)
    return record, index


def find_room_by_id(self, id: UUID | str, where: list[Room]) -> RoomWithIndex | None:
    f = lambda room: room.id == id
    return find_value_by_attr(where, f)

def find_room_by_session(self, session: SocketIOUserSessionID, where: list[Room]) -> RoomWithIndex | None:
    f = lambda room: session in room.sessions
    return find_value_by_attr(where, f)
...

Because in case of just one-for-all function you will need to join your typings which will lead to a situation when they can mix like for example UUID | str for id in the first func and RSStateWithIndex for the output of the third one. It'll break your logic.

I figured out how to make a generic function with help of "operator" module.
Here we go:
import operator


def find_model(
    needle: str,
    haystack: list[Any],
    operator_function: Callable[[Any, Any], Any] = operator.eq,
    filter_by: str = "id",
) -> tuple[Any, int] | None:
    if model := next(filter(lambda model: operator_function(getattr(model, filter_by), needle), haystack), None):
        return model, haystack.index(model)
    return None


self.find_model(needle=room_id, haystack=rooms, operator_function=operator.eq, filter_by="id")
self.find_model(needle=session, haystack=rooms, operator_function=operator.contains, filter_by="sessions")

